# How to calculate mean of multiple standard deviation in R

Tags: r, mean, deviation

i have a little problem i have 10 standard deviation and 10 mean with normal distribution like this
N(5,1) , N(10,3), N(8,2) N(6,1), N(10,3), N(7,2), N(4,1), N(10,3), N(9,2), N(8,1).
if i search the mean of total mean in R the code is

```
c=cbind(c(5,10,8,6,10,7,4,10,9,8))
y=mean(c)
```

so how to calculate average of standard deviation, but this average doesnt like the formula average as always?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you correctly, but if you have a vector of standard deviations, you can also just calculate the mean.

So e.g.

```
my_sd = c(1.23, 4.53, 3.343)

mean(my_sd)
```

If your quesiton is about how to calculate a standard deviation, this can be done easily with the `sd` function.

Comment: i mean not mean or standard deviation, but i mean is the average of standard deviation but the formula it doesnt like average formula

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what error appears in your console.
May it be because you lack a `)` at the end of your `cbind` function?
As you can see below, I can calculate mean of `c` without issue.

```
> c <- cbind(c(5,10,8,6,10,7,4,10,9,8))
> y <- mean(c)
> y 
[1] 7.7
```

Comment: this is the formula of average of mean not average of standard deviation, but i mean the average of standard deviation is not like average formula like usual

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your objective is.  But averaging the standard deviations obscures the relationships between the standard deviations and the associated means.  For instance N(25, 2) and N(5, 5) would have much different summary statistics than N(25, 5) and N(5, 2).  Even though the averages of the means and standard deviations would be the same.  A better statistic could be the average of the Coeffficients of Variation of each of the distributions.  So:

```
ms <- c(5,10,8,6,10,7,4,10,9,8)
sds <- c(1,3,2,1,3,2,1,3,2,1)
cvs <- sds/ms
[1] 0.2000000 0.3000000 0.2500000 0.1666667 0.3000000 0.2857143 0.2500000 0.3000000 0.2222222 0.1250000
meancvs <- mean(cvs)
[1] 0.2399603
```